# Django Downloaded File Name

Tags: python, django, view, download

I use a simple view class to "force download" a file by its pk. The file downloaded name comes out to be the pk. I would like it to be the original file name, like it is on the server.
How do i do that?

*Im new to django

here the view's code

```
class GetFileContent(View):
def get(self,request, userName, pk):
    user = User.objects.filter(username = userName)
    filtered = File.objects.filter(pk = pk, published=True, file_owner = user)
    data = filtered[0].content
    return HttpResponse(data, content_type='application/force-download')
    pass
```

Comment: In addition to Simeons answer I also suggest to deliver files via mod_xsendfile if you use apache and have root access to configure it.

Answer (score 11):

You need to set the filename on the response:

```
response = HttpResponse(data, content_type='application/force-download')
response['Content-Disposition'] = f'attachment; filename={filename}' # F-strings are typically more readable and efficient compared to the str.format() method. However, if you're working with older Python versions, you may need to use str.format()
return response
```

You'll need to figure out a way to determine the desired filename (e..g, by storing it in the database as well for lookups).